# Accordion change color of single element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a jQuery accordion with the following markup

```
<div id="accordion">
    <div class="group" id="1">
        <div class="title">
            <a href="">Title 1</a></div>
        <div class="body">
            Body 1<br />
            <br />
            <form>
                Test <input type="text" /><br />
                <br />
                Test <input type="text" /><br />
                <br />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="group" id="2">
        <div class="title">
            <a href="">Title 2</a></div>
        <div class="body">
            Body 2<br />
            <br />
            <form>
                Test <input type="text" /><br />
                <br />
                Test <input type="text" /><br />
                <br />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have included a jsfiddle here

http://jsfiddle.net/nLHpR/

How can I use javascript to change the background color of one of the accordion elements? For example, if I wanted to change the background color of accordion element with id = "1" to red, how would I do it?

I tried doing

```
$("#1").css('background-color','red');
```

and it did not work. I then tried

```
$("#1").children().css('background-color','red');
```

and it partially works but there are many areas which remain white (see jsfiddle link)

Comment: $("#1").css('background-color','red'); should work ... check the class CSS for the same element

Comment: @Reflective - #1 moves into the background and coloring it does not cause the accordion element to turn red. Sushanth's answer below is the correct one.

Comment: as i told you - check the css for the same element :) there is already defined inherited `background: ....` ...so changing just the color will not reflet already defined background image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override a class in the Jquery UI CSS to do so,

```
#1 .ui-widget-content
{
    background: red !important;
}​
```

Because the background attribute given by the CSS has a image which seems to be overlapping it. So you need to give the backgroundcolor to this class and not the div directly..

```
$("#1 .ui-widget-content").css('background','red');
```

**EDIT**

```
.ui-accordion-icons .ui-accordion-header a {
    background: orange !important;
}​
```

[CHECK FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/nLHpR/29/)

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly what I was looking for. Do you know how I can also color the header red? Your fiddle shows the body in red but header in white

Comment: just set `$("#1").css('background','red');` if you prefer to use JS

Comment: The problem with the solution is that overriding susanth all ui widgets, so if there are other UI elements on the page, these take the red background.

Comment: You can always specify a container in which these changes to take place.. If you prepend your class with the divid,  then only the accordion in that particular div will only be affected

Answer (score 1):

`$("#1").css('background','red');` - background is defined in `.ui-widget-content` ... so you should override the whole background, otherwise background-image will presist

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the class ui-widget-content from the accordion widget. This class has

```
.ui-widget-content {
    border: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170);
    background: url("images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png") repeat-x scroll 50% 50% rgb(255, 255, 255);
    color: rgb(34, 34, 34);
}
```

This is the solution override the class and put the other properties of the class except the background

```
$("#1").children(".body").removeClass("ui-widget-content");
$("#1").children("form").css('color','rgb(34, 34, 34)');
$("#1").children(".body").css('border', '1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170)' );
```